# Using Powershell and Test-Path, how can I tell the difference between a "folder doesn't exist" and "access denied"

Tags: powershell

Using the Test-Path command in powershell, how can I tell the difference between a "folder doesn't exist" and "access denied"?

Comment: Access denied probably throws an exception, so you can catch that. If a path doesn't exist, `Test-Path` will just return `$false`.

Comment: @arco444 that ends up not being true. `Test-Path` will often work when the user doesn't actually have any permissions to the given item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: The good news is that `Test-Path` will often not return false even when you lack permissions (and when it doesn't, you'll get an exception instead of a simple `$false`)

In more depth, it depends on what you mean by access denied. Depending on what permissions you are looking to check, will depend on what PowerShell command will work for you.

For example, *C:\System Volume Information* is a folder that non-administrators have no permissions for. `Test-Path` returns true for this folder - it exists - even though you can't access it. On the other hand, running `Get-Child-Item` fails. So in this case, you would need to run

```
$path = 'C:\System Volume Information'
if ((Test-Path $path) -eq $true)
{
    gci $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($Error[0].Exception -is [System.UnauthorizedAccessException])
    {
        # your code here
        Write-Host "unable to access $path"
    }
}
```

If however, you have read permissions but not write permissions, then you'll have to actually attempt to write to the file, or look at its security permissions and try to figure out what applies to the current user the script is running under:

```
(get-acl C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).Access
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
Test-Path $PathToFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

then test and see if it's UnAuthorized

```
$Error[0].Exception.GetType()
```

Comment: This doesn't work well because $Error[0].Exception does not refer to the last call to Test-Path. The error can have happened anywhere in the whole script.

Answer (score -1):

`Resolve-Path` will do the job, if path not found, will throw an error.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx

Comment: How does that distinguish between "Access Denied" and "Path not Found?" Doesn't that muddy the waters even more, by giving an error for both, instead of an error and $false, respectively?