# Test-Path is returning true even if the network path is not accessible (the path is present though)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using Test-Path to test if i have access to a particular network path or not.

Test-path is returning TRUE even though i dont have access to the network share.

I am trying to check for the path where it is present but i dont have access to it.

How do i check in powershell to see if the network share is accessible or not to me, it should give "share is not present and access denied"(Please note that network share could be present or not)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only true solution in this case is to try and write an empty file to the destination folder. For more explanation check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588181/using-powershell-and-test-path-how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-a-folder)

Comment: Good link, but if this particular question is _essentially the same_ as the question you link to (which I believe is true), it's better to simply mark this question as a duplicate (by clicking on the "close" link and selecting "duplicate of...").